# Unir dos dataFrame pandas

Tags: pandas

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

inicio = datetime(2017, 1, 30)
final =  datetime(2019, 3, 21)

datos = []

for i in range (0, 10000):
    datos.append(inicio + (final - inicio) * random.random())

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

df.rename(columns={0: "Fecha"}, inplace=True)

procesos = []

for a in range (1, 11):
    procesos.append('Proceso' + str(a))

total = 0

proceso = []

for i in range (0, 10):
    for j in range ( 0, 1000):
        proceso.append(procesos[total])
    total += 1

datosProceso = pd.DataFrame(proceso)

datosProceso.rename(index=str, columns={0: "Proceso"}, inplace=True)
```

Esto crea dos df con 10.000 datos aleatorios, uno tiene 10.000 fechas y el otro tiene 10.000 datos de procesos separados en 10 procesos aleatorios o sea 1000 datos de proceso1, 1000 datos de proceso2, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ahora como podria unir los dos dataframe en uno solo que tenga dos columnas, procesos y fechas, probe agregando ids, con concat pero lo tira abajo, join me da error, etc.**

Sin usar los dos DF que se arman rápido lo hago de esta forma pero que tarda 2 a 3 min porque va linea a linea en la posición suplantando el valor ademas de que tira SettingWithCopyWarning:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

inicio = datetime(2017, 1, 30)
final =  datetime(2019, 3, 21)

datos = []

for i in range (0, 10000):
    datos.append(inicio + (final - inicio) * random.random())

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

df.rename(columns={0: "Fecha"}, inplace=True)

df['proceso'] = ''

procesos = []
for a in range (1, 11):
    procesos.append('Proceso' + str(a))

total = 0
posicion = 0

for i in range (0, 10):
    for j in range ( 0, 1000):
        df['proceso'][posicion] = procesos[total]
        print(posicion)
        posicion += 1
    total += 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que complica es el índice de los dos `dataframes` al ser distintos las opciones de `merge` no funcionan como lo quisiéramos en estos casos. Lo que se puede hacer es inicializar el índice de los dos `data.frame` a un simple número secuencial, cosa que podemos hacer con [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index)

```
result = pd.merge(df.reset_index(),
                  datosProceso.reset_index(), 
                  left_index=True, 
                  right_index=True)
```

Conceptualmente, de esta forma, los dos `dataframes` terminan teniendo un mismo índice `(1:9999)` con lo cual ahora sí, el `merge()` hace lo que esperamos: unir secuencialmente ambos `dataframes`.

Comment: Mira vos, yo lo usaba cuando tenia indices numéricos adicionales y eliminaba columnas no sabia que creaba la columna con el indice auto incrementable, muchas gracias, es mucho mas rápido así, ya con la nueva columna y el indice puedo hacer el merge que antes no podía, ya despues con result = result.drop(columns={'index_x', 'index_y'}) dejo solo las columnas que necesito en ese nuevo df