# Eliminar duplicados y mostrar en una columna el total de veces que se repetía la fila completa

Tags: pandas

Vengo arrastrando consultas desde este problema:

[Unir dos dataFrame pandas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247703/unir-dos-dataframe-pandas)

Usando este código:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

inicio = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
final =  datetime(2019, 3, 21)

datos = []

for i in range (0, 10000):
    fechaRandom = inicio + (final - inicio) * random.random() 
    datos.append(fechaRandom.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

df.rename(columns={0: "Fecha"}, inplace=True)

procesos = []

for a in range (1, 11):
    procesos.append('Proceso' + str(a))

total = 0

proceso = []

for i in range (0, 10):
    for j in range ( 0, 1000):
        proceso.append(procesos[total])
    total += 1

datosProceso = pd.DataFrame(proceso)

datosProceso.rename(index=str, columns={0: "Proceso"}, inplace=True)

result = pd.merge(datosProceso.reset_index(),
              df.reset_index(),
              left_index=True, 
              right_index=True)

result = result.drop(columns={'index_x', 'index_y'})
```

Obtengo lo siguiente:

Un Df con 10.000 datos aleatorios en dos columnas, procesos y fechas (Con 10.000 fechas aleatorias agrupadas en 10 procesos aleatorios de a 1000 registros cada uno)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito ahora es poder sacar los duplicados, y dejar el proceso mas la fecha y en una columna el total de veces que se repitió esa fecha para ese proceso.
En resumen es esto:

```
(result
.groupby(["Proceso", "Fecha"]) 
["Fecha"].count())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que necesito que todo este en un nuevo Dataframe que tenga este formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado:

Me complique la vida haciendo otras cosas, era solo esto.
Dejo la pregunta porque le puede llegar a servir a alguien.

```
result = result.groupby(['Proceso', 'Fecha']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

otra posibilidad por si se necesita pasar a una lista:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(list(zip(result.Proceso, result.Fecha)))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]